# ImageResource.ts:182 Uncaught (in promise), with PIXI and Typescript no texture loads using pixi and texturepacker

Tags: typescript, pixi.js, texturepacker

I am trying to do something very simple with PIXI and Typescript. I decided to switch to using texture packer from loading individual png files and ran into this issue.
The issue is when trying to access the texture that is loaded through the spritesheet json file I get a promise error. The code is very simple and I have tried various ways of doing this with no luck. This example is the simplest and uses the example from CodeAndWeb (Texture packer devs site) but in an attempt to translate it to typescript and separated the functionality a bit. Any advice is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Code Sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-hooks-9g8j6?file=/src/index.ts

```
import { Container, Sprite, Graphics, Texture, Spritesheet } from "pixi.js";
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";


// This example is based on the following
// https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/how-to-create-sprite-sheets-and-animations-with-pixijs5

export class Game extends Container {
    
    static GAME_WIDTH = 320;
    static GAME_HEIGHT = 568;  

    private static _instance: Game;

    public app: PIXI.Application | undefined;


    constructor() {

        super();

        window.onload = (): void => {
            
            this.createRenderer();  
            this.addAssets();
            this.startLoadingAssets();
        };

        console.log('Game Constructed');
    }

    public static getInstance(): Game {

        if (!Game._instance) {
            Game._instance = new Game();
        }

        return Game._instance;
    }
    
    private addAssets(): void {
        
        PIXI.Loader.shared.add('game', '../assets/game.json');
        
        console.log('Assets added');
    }

    private startLoadingAssets(): void {        
        
        PIXI.Loader.shared.onComplete.add(() => { this.onAssetsLoaded(); });
        // PIXI.Loader.shared.onComplete.add(this.onAssetsLoaded);
        PIXI.Loader.shared.load();
        console.log('Loading assets');
        
    }   
     
    private onAssetsLoaded(): void {
        let sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.from("backBoard.png"));

        // let sheet = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources["../assets/game.json"];
        // let sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(sheet.texture['backBoard,png']);

        // this.app?.stage.addChild(sprite);

        console.log('AssetsLoaded');
    }

    private createRenderer(): void {

        this.app = new PIXI.Application({
            backgroundColor: 0x001320,
        })

        document.body.appendChild(this.app.view);        
 
        console.log('Renderer Created');
    }

    public initialize(): void {


        console.log('Game initialized');
    }
    

}
```

json looks like this

```
{"frames": {

"backBoard.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1,"y":1,"w":318,"h":442},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":318,"h":442},
    "sourceSize": {"w":318,"h":442}
},
"buttonDisabled.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":321,"y":340,"w":30,"h":30},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":30,"h":30},
    "sourceSize": {"w":30,"h":30}
},
"buttonDown.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":353,"y":344,"w":30,"h":30},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":30,"h":30},
    "sourceSize": {"w":30,"h":30}
},
"buttonSmallDisabled.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":395,"y":224,"w":22,"h":22},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":22,"h":22},
    "sourceSize": {"w":22,"h":22}
},
"buttonSmallDown.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":395,"y":248,"w":22,"h":22},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":22,"h":22},
    "sourceSize": {"w":22,"h":22}
},
"buttonSmallUp.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":395,"y":272,"w":22,"h":22},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":22,"h":22},
    "sourceSize": {"w":22,"h":22}
},
"buttonUp.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":321,"y":372,"w":30,"h":30},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":30,"h":30},
    "sourceSize": {"w":30,"h":30}
},
"coin.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":368,"y":311,"w":31,"h":33},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":31,"h":33},
    "sourceSize": {"w":31,"h":33}
},
"logo.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":321,"y":213,"w":125,"h":45},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":125,"h":45},
    "sourceSize": {"w":125,"h":45}
},
"meter_big.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":321,"y":100,"w":92,"h":47},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":92,"h":47},
    "sourceSize": {"w":92,"h":47}
},
"meter_small.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":368,"y":213,"w":43,"h":25},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":43,"h":25},
    "sourceSize": {"w":43,"h":25}
},
"meterDisplay.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":321,"y":149,"w":89,"h":49},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":89,"h":49},
    "sourceSize": {"w":89,"h":49}
},
"meterDisplayBig.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":321,"y":1,"w":97,"h":97},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":97,"h":97},
    "sourceSize": {"w":97,"h":97}
},
"meterMinus.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":368,"y":258,"w":25,"h":25},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":25,"h":25},
    "sourceSize": {"w":25,"h":25}
},
"meterPlus.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":368,"y":285,"w":24,"h":24},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":24,"h":24},
    "sourceSize": {"w":24,"h":24}
},
"peg.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":399,"y":200,"w":11,"h":22},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":11,"h":22},
    "sourceSize": {"w":11,"h":22}
},
"target_guide.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":321,"y":200,"w":11,"h":76},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":11,"h":76},
    "sourceSize": {"w":11,"h":76}
}},
"meta": {
    "app": "https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker",
    "version": "1.0",
    "image": "cheenko.png",
    "format": "RGBA8888",
    "size": {"w":419,"h":444},
    "scale": "1",
    "smartupdate": "$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:507f67780e7f85c65d491493063f25f9:181b9d624fffd3a88b16c67d21e19ad7:3dbd62212b1a89304e8d06008f40f33d$"
}
}
```

Comment: what is the error? (message, stack trace etc?)

Comment: Hello, I have added to a code sandbox right here
https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-hooks-9g8j6?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: This has been solved. The following link has the answer
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-surf-0kdci

Comment: so the `crossOrigin: "*"` added in loader helped?

Comment: @domis86 only in the codesanbox version I am using parcel to host locally and I am starting to wonder if that is the issue. Here is the git repo link 
https://github.com/420visions/spritesheet_issue
This is the same exact code and example yet it does not work with either of the spritesheets that are in the assets folder. Not sure what is causing the uncaught in promise errror

Comment: by "host locally" you are really hosting image via web server? Or you try to include it somehow without hosting? If is the latter then it will probably fail. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41771494/3174731  or https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/45533-cross-origin-on-localhost/?do=findComment&comment=251573   . Also watch out for "cross origin" problems (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22856981/3174731 etc )

Comment: The answer was to use this parcel plugin
https://github.com/elwin013/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this question, I've had the exact same error. It was hard for me to find solutions on StackOverflow, but in the end, I figured it out.

First, if you want to use a public server, it'll have to have CORs enabled. Then, it should work fine.

If you want to use an image hosted on a local server (e.g. using the `http-server` package to run a local file repository), for the image source, you'll have to use the full link – e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8001` instead of something like `localhost:8001`, which won't work. You'll also have to enable the CORs option (for instance, for `http-server`, that would mean adding the `--cors` flag)